# Simple Bash - for f in *

Tags: file, bash, loops, for-loop

Consider this simple loop:

```
for f in *.{text,txt}; do echo $f; done
```

I want to echo ONLY valid file names. Using the $f variable in a script everything works great unless there aren't any files of that extension. In the case of an empty set, $f is set to *.text and the above line echos:

```
*.text
*.txt
```

rather than echoing nothing. This creates an error if you are trying to use $f for anything that is expecting an actual real file name and instead gets *.

If there are any files that match the wildcard so that it is not an empty set everything works as I would like. e.g.

```
123.text
456.txt
789.txt
```

How can I do this without the errors and without seemingly excessive complexity of first string matching $f for an asterisk?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Set the `nullglob` option.

```
$ for f in *.foo ; do echo "$f" ; done
*.foo
$ shopt -s nullglob
$ for f in *.foo ; do echo "$f" ; done
$
```

Answer (score 4):

You can test if the file actually exists:

```
for f in *.{text,txt}; do if [ -f $f ]; then echo $f; fi; done
```

or you can use the `find` command:

```
for f in $(find -name '*.text' -o -name '*.txt'); do
  echo $f
done
```

Comment: Testing if $f is in fact a file works well enough. But, it is an additional test that I had hoped to avoid.

Comment: Is this perhaps relevant here? https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/321697/why-is-looping-over-finds-output-bad-practice

Answer (score 0):

Also, if you can afford the external use of `ls`, you can escape its results by using

```
for f in `ls *.txt *.text`;
```

Comment: Which can be fixed by setting `$IFS` correctly. In contrast to the nullglob option, this can happen fairly safely inside a shell script without calling out to shopt.

Comment: Please show how. Also, `shopt` is a builtin, so you do not call it "out".

Comment: IFS=$'\n'; (loop here); unset $IFS; It's not rocket science.

Comment: There are other characters in file names that can cause problems which changing `IFS` won't fix: quotes, pipes, ampersands... anything which has special meaning to the shell.

Comment: `ls` is useful for a person, but there are better ways to iterate over files.